# Pointers and Objects in C++, x86 Compilation Error

Tags: c++, oop, object, pointers, x86

I'm creating a binary tree by linking individual nodes all the way up to the root node, which I return from the method.

```
MaxWinnerTree::MaxWinnerTree(int elements)
    {
        WinnerTree(elements);
    }

`Node MaxWinnerTree::WinnerTree(int elements)
{   

int size = 1;
while (size<elements)
    size = size * 2; //gets closest power of 2 to create full bottom row

Node* a[size]; //array of pointers to nodes

for (int i = (2*elements-1); i>0; i--)
{
    //Create nodes and link them to parent, right, and left values

    if (i > elements-1) //leaf
    {   
        //Create new nodes with data -1, store pointer to it in array
        *a[i] = newNode(i,-1,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    }

    else    // not leaf
    {   
        //Create node with data = max of children, store pointer
        *a[i] = newNode(i,-1,a[i*2],a[i*2 +1], NULL); //create
        a[i]->data = max(a[i*2]->data, a[i*2+1]->data); //gets max
        a[i]->right->parent = a[i];
        a[i]->left->parent = a[i];

        if(i=1)
            root = a[i];

    }
}

return *root; }
```

However, trying to create an object in my main method isn't working like it should.

```
MaxWinnerTree* tree = new MaxWinnerTree(elements);
```

Gives a standard x86 architecture error, where as

```
MaxWinnerTree tree = new MaxWinnerTree(elements);
```

Gives

```
main.cpp:22: error: invalid conversion from ‘MaxWinnerTree*’ to ‘int’
main.cpp:22: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘MaxWinnerTree::MaxWinnerTree(int)’
```

Why does the compiler think that my method is returning an int? What is to correct way to create an object in this fashion? In reality, I just need a pointer to the root node, where all my other methods will begin.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: This assignment is assuredly incorrect: `*a[i] = newNode(i,-1,NULL,NULL,NULL);`.   You want to assign a new pointer to the array element `a[i]`, so the first part should be `a[i] =`.  Now, what does `newNode` return?  Also, are you sure you want to return `Node` from `WinnerTree` and not `Node*`?

Comment: As far as constructing your object:  Without a valid copy constructor, you need to write either your first statement (`MaxWinnerTree* tree = new MaxWinnerTree(elements);`) or avoid `new` altogether: `MaxWinnerTree tree(elements);`.

Answer (score 1):

Changes I would make:

1. Change `newNode` (which you haven't shown us) to return a `Node *`.  If `newNode` isn't actually allocating a new `Node`, then you need to rethink its design.  Or, move the arguments to `newNode` into a constructor for `Node`, and change your code to read `new Node( ... args ... )`.
2. Instead of saying `*a[i] = newNode( ... )` say `a[i] = newNode( ... )` (or whatever you replace `newNode` with as per my first bullet).  What you have written asks the C++ compiler to invoke a copy constructor to copy whatever `newNode` returned into the object pointed to by `*a[i]`, but from the snippet you shared with us, `*a[i]` doesn't point to anything yet.
3. You've built a heap, but with explicit pointers.  If you really wanted a heap, you don't need the explicit pointers...
4. This next line can just ruin your whole day.  `i=1` assigns 1 to `i` and then returns `1` as its value, which doesn't really do the right thing.  In your case, it'll make your loop stop iterating as soon as it gets to the part of the heap-building where the elements have children.

   ```
   if(i=1)
       root = a[i];
   ```